# Change key name row

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I change the key name of array value ?

Like in this query:

```
SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(ROW(1, 'foo'));
```

result :

```
{"f1": 1, "f2": "foo"}
```

How can I change the default key name (f1, f2) like that:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}
```

Comment: does `ROW` accept something like `AS` on it?  `1 as id, 'foo' as name`

Comment: no, ROW accept only value parameters

Comment: see relevant question on dba.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/set-names-to-attributes-when-creating-json-with-row-to-json

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_to_json(s)
from (values (1, 'foo')) s(id, name);
      row_to_json      
-----------------------
 {"id":1,"name":"foo"}
```